# How to execute view code stored in string in run time with eval in Rails 3.2 erb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, eval

What we are trying to do is to store a chunk of `erb` code in a `string` and then execute the code in run time. Here is a test we did :

1. take out a chunk of the code from a working erb file and,
2. rewrite the erb file with eval.

Here is the chunk of erb code taken out:

```
<tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th><%= t('Date') %></th>
      <th><%= t('Project Name') %></th>
      <th><%= t('Task Name') %></th>
      <th><%= t('Log') %></th>
      <th><%= t('Entered By') %></th>
  
    </tr>

    <% @logs.each do |r| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= r.id %></td>
          <td><%= (r.created_at + 8.hours).strftime("%Y/%m/%d")%></td>
          <td><%= prt(r, 'task.project.name') %></td>
          <td><%= prt(r, 'task.task_template.task_definition.name') %></td>
          <td><%= prt(r, :log) %></td>
          <td><%= prt(r, 'last_updated_by.name') %></td>
          
        </tr>
    <% end %>
```

`t()` is the translation method for internationalization.

Here is the erb file after rewriting:

```
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <% code = find_config_const('task_log_view', 'projectx')%>
    <%= eval(code)%>

  </table>
```

Before rewriting, the chunk of code goes between `<table>`. Now variable `code` returns a `string` of the chunk of code and `eval` execute the chunk of code. But here is the error:

```
(eval):1: syntax error, unexpected '<'
(eval):4: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting $end
      <th><%= t('Project Name') %></th>
               ^

Extracted source (around line #6):

4:   <table class="table table-striped">
5:      <% code = find_config_const('task_log_view', 'projectx')%>
6:     <%= eval(code)%>
7: 
8:   </table>
9:
```

What's wrong with the code above?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`eval` works by evaluating ruby code.

```
irb(main):001:0> eval('puts "Hello World"')
Hello World
=> nil
```

while Converting erb template should be done with `ERB` class

```
irb(main):002:0> require 'erb'
irb(main):003:0> ERB.new('<%= "Hello World" %>').result
=> "Hello World"
```

My guess is that the `code` is actually a string that contain ERB template rather than ruby code.

Nonetheless I don't think that this is a good approach. `task.project.name` are probably from database that possibly came from user input. doing eval on that seems not like a good idea.

Probably you could solve your problem with normal `partials`

Comment: ERB may do the trick. We need to run code from a trusted source at run time. Partial can not do that.

Comment: If you call `ERB.new` from another scope such as a helper you'll need to pass the local `binding` as a parameter into it's `result` method `def foo(binding); ERB.new('<%= "Hello World" %>').result(binding); end`.  If it's html then you need to add `.html_safe` on the end.