# render rails code in raw output

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have written a simple CMS and output some text as html via

```
<%= raw @page.body %>
```

Since the CMS is for my own usage, I want to be able to also enter rails code in the body text. When entering it there, I get something like this as output:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
>   eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <%= @foo
>   %>. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
>   eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

but I want the rails code <%= @foo %> to render and not be plain text.

Comment: You need to actively evaluate the code using ERB. Maybe this answer can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18114185/how-to-execute-view-code-stored-in-string-in-run-time-with-eval-in-rails-3-2-erb

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to render html content with erb tags in rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19312487/how-to-render-html-content-with-erb-tags-in-rails)